# Modify the value of CNTFRQ_EL0 in ARM KVM for the guest to boot

Tags: windows, arm64, kvm

I found that there is a [patch](https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/7/21/525) for Linux to run on systems that have misprogrammed CNTFRQ register. From the patch:

> It is an unfortunate situation that CNTFRQ{,_EL0} is often
> misprogrammed from the firmware side, leaving it up to the kernel to
> work around it. This is usually done by providing an alternative
> frequency in the Device Tree.
> Unfortunately, CNTFRQ is accessible from EL0, giving userspace the
> wrong frequency, and potentially a different frequency per CPU, which
> is definitely not what you want. A possible workaround is to trap this
> into the kernel and to emulate it (together with the VDSO being
> disabled), and this is what this series is achieving.

From what I know, the CNTFRQ register is only writable from EL3 (monitor), and readable from all exception levels. Mine also has misconfigured CNTFRQ, it's set to 0 by bootloader (which I cannot modify).

What I want is to run Windows ARM on KVM on the host machine which also has misprogrammed CNTFRQ register. Windows just simply won't boot with CNTFRQ set to 0. Since Linux is an open source kernel, we can just apply patches in the code, but Windows is a commercial OS, so I think it's somewhat illegal to patch its code (and also harder to binary patch).

What I have think of:

- Trap and emulate the read from CNTFRQ in KVM
- Trap and emulate from QEMU
- (I think this is too slow) Use the same thing GDB use to list instructions from QEMU, then check if it's reading from CNTFRQ, then set the correct value to the read.
- Binary patch Windows (not sure where to patch).

Any ideas? Thank you in advance! Please correct me if I'm wrong.

---

**Edit 1**:
I loaded `ntoskrnl.exe` to IDA and then use a script called [`ida-arm-system-highlight`](https://github.com/gdelugre/ida-arm-system-highlight).

Then I searched for CNTFRQ and got 3 results:
[image: IDA search result]

The first one in the list:
[image: 1st search]

Note: [This](https://github.com/sleirsgoevy/exynos-kvm-patch/blob/59d6853d58f1a99bf432a78fc7443a7df458ca8f/edk2.patch#L12) is the patch I used to patch EDK2 to boot on my KVM, and it actually worked. The patch set the read `CNTFRQ_EL0` to be 26Mhz (26000000). So could I use that value to patch `CNTFRQ_EL0` read in `ntoskrnl.exe`?

Also, pretend that the value 26Mhz (`0x18CBA80`) works, when I tried replacing `MRS X8, #3, c14, c0, #0` with `LDR X8, =0x18CBA80`, it takes 3 instructions!

[image: take 3 instructions]

Any ideas? Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: You are right, `CNTFRQ` could be written only on EL3: `Can only be written at the highest Exception level implemented. For example, if EL3 is the highest implemented Exception level, CNTFRQ_EL0 can only be written at EL3`. So you cannot modify it. Aside 'legality' issues that I'm not qualified to talk about, I'd try binary patching. All you need is to convert `MSR CNTFRQ_EL0, <Xt>` instruction to binary (with compiler or just manually) and search it in binary blob. If `<Xt>` is assigned just before `MSR` instruction, patching should be trivial.

Comment: in reference manual `Traps and Enables: If CNTKCTL_EL1.EL0PCTEN==0, and CNTKCTL_EL1.EL0VCTEN==0, EL0 read accesses to this register are trapped to EL1`. I have not tried anything like that, but from description it seems that you could trap `MRS <Xt>, CNTFRQ_EL0` from `EL0`. In this case that possible to expand exception handler and put whatever you need into `<Xt>`. Though from your question I don't see if you have access to exception handlers code.

Comment: `edk2.patch` explicitly set freq to some 26MHz constant.  I don't have any ideas about win binary you are using. But sure you could use similar approach. Now from last picture it's not clear what surrounds `1403B2778 MSR #3,c14,c0,#0,x8`. First thing I'd do is to check if there is a few words gap around, put `ldr x29,=xxx, msr xxx, b 'back'` into it and replace original `msr` instruction with jump with offset to this gap. Note that that jump should be relative, you don't have room to load address into register, you likely should use other than `x8` because changing `x8` might affect code below